# How to convert a Vec<Vec<f64>> into a string

Tags: string, vector, rust

I am new to Rust, and I am struggling with a simple task. I'd like to convert a matrix into a string, with the fields separated by tabs. I think this is possible by using the `map` function or something similar, but right now whatever I try gives me an error.

This is what I have, and I'd like to convert the `col` part into function, which returns a tab separated string, which I can print.
In Python this is something like `row.join("\t")`. Is there something similar in Rust?

```
fn print_matrix(vec: &Vec<Vec<f64>>) {
    for row in vec.iter() {
        for col in row.iter() {
           print!("\t{:?}",col);
        }
        println!("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of this doesn't work? Can you provide a minimal, complete, example on the Playpen? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code.

Comment: it should print   string<tab>string<tab>string    but it prints a leading tab. there must be a more elegant solution than that, without fiddling

Comment: Look at the examples under https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#format_args

Answer (score 7):

There is indeed a `join` in the standard library, but it's not super useful (often additional allocation is required). But you can see a solution here:

```
fn print_matrix(vec: &Vec<Vec<f64>>) {
    for row in vec {
        let cols_str: Vec<_> = row.iter().map(ToString::to_string).collect();
        let line = cols_str.join("\t");
        println!("{}", line);
    }
}
```

The problem is that this `join` works with slices and not with iterators. We have to convert all elements into a string first, collect the result in a new vector and can use `join` then.

The crate [`itertools`](https://github.com/bluss/rust-itertools) defines a `join` method for iterators and can be applied like so:

```
for row in vec {
    let line = row.iter().join("\t");
    println!("{}", line);
}
```

And to avoid using any of the named functionality, you can of course do it manually:

```
for row in vec {
    if let Some(first) = row.get(0) {
        print!("{}", first);            
    }
    for col in row.iter().skip(1) {
        print!("\t{}", col);
    }
    println!("");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides `join` from `itertools` you could always use `fold` on iterator (which is really useful), like this:

```
row.iter().fold("", |tab, col| { print!("{}{:?}", tab, col); "\t" });
```

Comment: This will end with one extra `\t`